# Image Pixels Problem in Android?

Tags: android, background

When I am using the background attribute for a Layout, the Pixels of the background image looks like blurry. I think there must be a resolution Problem. for example in Api Demos there is a module in this path Graphics/BitmapsPixels. My background image is looks like a third image. i would need to show my background image like the second one. How to do this? Any tutorials, Samples are most Thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you image is an PNG and not a 9 patch png - you need just better image ( what size of the image you use ? ) . If its defined in XML - post the code

Comment: Can you open this image in the editor and post screen shot. Also put screenshot from device/emulator - and layout definition where you set it as background. Btw, what's resolution of your device ?

Comment: how to open it in editer. editer in the sense its in eclipse. right?

Comment: please help me. i know nothing about that editor? i struggling where to start?

Comment: i can edit the image in photoshop. i am using the custom title bar? because of that the screen size be mismatch with the image size. is that the problem of mine?